# Bitmap Indices on MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, olap, indices

I'm trying to design an OLAP DB in MySQL with the use of **Bitmap Indices**, however MySQL doesn't support Bitmap indices (as far as I know), so I have to build and maintain my own bitmap index.

Could someone tell me if this will still bring any benefit to my application, like speeding up multidimensional range queries ? If so, which would be the best way to implement it ?

Comment: To answer this question we need to know what kind of data you are using. Generally speaking this is better for alot of data which isn't that varied, like 50 million instances with only two or three possible values.

Comment: The data I have are like this: Table with attribute "numberOfVisitors" and an attribute for "month" which values are limited on 12  -> so I can splitt this in 12 rows, each row representing one month

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, "summary tables" is something to build into the application:

1. [Partitioning a 250+ million
   table](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?106,262613)
2. [Get statistics using self
   joins](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,262876)
3. [Slow query on large table - how to
   optimize?](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,261938)
4. [Query optimization or better table
       design?](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?125,260917)
5. [Index not being
       used](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?115,257729)
6. [Union on 55+ tables killing web
       app](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,258287)
7. [Need help to improve innodb
       performance](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,255023)
8. [Huge Table - Slow query - Can I
       index
       better?](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,257758)
9. [InnoDB CPU
       Spikes](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,253221)
10. [Extreme high load and low
         throughput using MySQL & Hybris
         on an HP DL380G5, quad-core Intel,
         4GB
         RAM](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,253489)
11. [Poor Performance with tables over
         1Million
         entries](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,256929)

Comment: Actually I wanted to know if the "Bitmap indices" approach will still bring any benefit to my application using MySQL, since MySQL doesn't offer any support for this type of indexing.

Comment: my implementation would be based on the description of "Bitmap index Design" on this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.60.2771&rank=1)